# Joining two HDFS files in in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I want to join two files from HDFS using spark shell.
Both the files are tab separated and I want to join on second column

Tried code
But not giving any output

```
val ny_daily= sc.parallelize(List("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/user/NYstock  /NYSE_daily"))

val ny_daily_split = ny_daily.map(line =>line.split('\t'))

val enKeyValuePair = ny_daily_split.map(line => (line(0).substring(0, 5), line(3).toInt))


val ny_dividend= sc.parallelize(List("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/user/NYstock/NYSE_dividends"))

val ny_dividend_split = ny_dividend.map(line =>line.split('\t'))

val enKeyValuePair1 = ny_dividend_split.map(line => (line(0).substring(0, 4),     line(3).toInt))

enKeyValuePair1.join(enKeyValuePair)
```

But I am not getting any information for how to join files on particular column
Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

> I am not getting any information for how to join files on particular column

RDDs are joined on their keys, so you *decided* the column to join on when you wrote:

```
val enKeyValuePair = ny_daily_split.map(line => (line(0).substring(0, 5), line(3).toInt))
...
val enKeyValuePair1 = ny_daily_split.map(line => (line(0).substring(0, 4), line(3).toInt))
```

Your RDDs will be joined on the values coming from `line(0).substring(0, 5)` and `line(0).substring(0, 4)`.

You can find the `join` function (and many other useful functions) [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) and the [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html) is a great reference to understand how Spark works.

> Tried code But not giving any output

In order to see the output, you have to ask Spark to print it:

```
enKeyValuePair1.join(enKeyValuePair).foreach(println)
```

**Note:** to load data from files you should use `sc.textFile()`: `sc.parallelize()` is only used to make RDDs out of Scala collections.

The following code should do the job:

```
val ny_daily_split = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/user/NYstock/NYSE_daily").map(line =>line.split('\t'))
val ny_dividend_split = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/user/NYstock/NYSE_dividends").map(line =>line.split('\t'))

val enKeyValuePair = ny_daily_split.map(line => line(0).substring(0, 5) -> line(3).toInt)
val enKeyValuePair1 = ny_dividend_split.map(line => line(0).substring(0, 4) -> line(3).toInt)

enKeyValuePair1.join(enKeyValuePair).foreach(println)
```

By the way, you mentioned that you want to join on the second column but you are actually using `line(0)`, is this intended?

Hope this helps!

Comment: what exactly i should put in JOIN's key and value as i want to join on column and as output i should be able to see entire joined dataset

Comment: then change your `map` functions to `ny_daily_split.map(line => line(1) -> line.mkString("\t"))` and `ny_dividend_split.map(line => line(1) -> line.mkString("\t"))` respectively.